# Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, yaml, logstash, opensearch

I've been trying to run a very simple SQL query from `logstash.yml` file and making a query to AWS opensearch.

logstash.yml file:

```
input {
    jdbc {
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://abcxyz.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/k***"
            jdbc_user => "k***"
            jdbc_password => "p**********s"
            jdbc_driver_library => "/path/to/postgresql-42.3.0.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
            jdbc_paging_enabled => true
            tracking_column => "unix_ts_in_secs"
            use_column_value => true
            tracking_column_type => "numeric"
            schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"

            statement => 'SELECT name FROM "User_profile"'
            # statement => 'SELECT * FROM "Video_Videos"'
    }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        copy => { "id" => "[@metadata][_id]"}
        remove_field => ["id", "@version", "unix_ts_in_secs"]
    }
}
output {
    opensearch {
            hosts => "https://xyz.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443"
            user => "k**h"
            password => "E****"
            index => "rdbms_sync_idx"
            document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
            ssl => true
            ssl_certificate_verification => false
    }
}
```

but whenever I try to run:
`./logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/cp_logstash.yml` from my command terminal,

I get the following error trace[updated]:

```
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
[INFO ] 2021-12-24 04:19:02.723 [main] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.16.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.20.1 (2.5.8) 2021-11-30 2a2962fbd1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.13+8 on 11.0.13+8 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[WARN ] 2021-12-24 04:19:03.460 [LogStash::Runner] multilocal - Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[FATAL] 2021-12-24 04:19:03.484 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Logstash could not be started because there is already another instance using the configured data directory.  If you wish to run multiple instances, you must change the "path.data" setting.
[FATAL] 2021-12-24 04:19:03.487 [LogStash::Runner] Logstash - Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.20.1.jar:?]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.20.1.jar:?]
    at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:94) ~[?:?]
```

Not sure how to fix these errors. Any suggestions ?

thanks,

Comment: If you are using the Elastic version of logstash then the opensearch output is not bundled with it. Are you using Elastic logstash or OSS logstash?

Comment: @Badger how can i check which one am i using ? 
from logstash yml file, i can see opensearch keyword in the 'output' part.

Comment: updated error logs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mentioned on this line:

> Logstash could not be started because there is already another instance using the configured data directory.  If you wish to run multiple instances, you must change the "path.data" setting.

This means you're running another instance of Logstash on the same host that shares the same data directory and that's not allowed.

Simply make sure that each instance has a different `path.data` setting in their respective configurations.

Comment: sudo systemctl status logstash
sudo systemctl stop logstash
./logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.yml

getting same error after these 3 commands as well

Comment: how can i change this ```path.data``` setting ?

Comment: Here is a good way to achieve this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/solved-multiple-instances-for-logstash/65539/2?u=theuntergeek